# Which of the following statements are definitely correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Which of the following statements are definitely correct?

> A) $f(x)=0$ is both even and odd function
>
> B) The degree of zero polynomial is zero
>
> C) If $(f \circ g)(x)$ is surjective, then  $g(x)$ is also surjective function
>
> D) If $(f \circ g)(x)$ is one-to-one , then $f(x)$ is also one-to-one function
>
> E) The degree of constant polynomial is zero.

---

My attempts:

$A)$ This is correct, because by definition

$f(-x)=-f(x)=0$ and $f(-x)=f(x)=0$.
if $f(x)=0,\;\forall x\in\mathbb R$

$B)$ This is incorrect. Because, degree of zero polynomial is $-\infty$.

$E)$ This is inorrect. Because,  zero polynomial is also a constant polynomial.

I can't continue from here. Because, I can not understand exactly what is surjective function. For example

The function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2$ ,then $f(x)$ is not surjective, but the function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R_+$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is surjective function.

Thus, is the surjectivity of $f(x)$ not dependent on the function itself? I can not understand...

And I can't say anything about $f(g(x))$ (surjective or bijective) because I didn't fully understand the subject..

Can you explain me $C$ and $D$?

$D)$ This is incorrect. Because,

I think that the, $f(g(x))$ is an one-to-one is in only range of $g(x)$.

Are my claims correct?

Comment: For C and D, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) has some info.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you very much. My understanding is scarce. I need to work on exact examples...on exact function examples. I'm currently reading the wiki

Comment: You might note that you're claiming $0=-\infty$ here...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Is $f:Z^{+}\rightarrow R$ and $f(x)=0$. Is this a constant function?

Comment: Yes, the function that's identically zero is certainly constant...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint about C). Assume $f\circ g$ is surjective. Then for any $y$ in the codomain of $f$ you can find $x$ in the domain of $g$ such that $f(g(x)) = y$. This means $f$ is surjective, because $g(x)$ is a preimage of $y$ under $f$.

To see that $g$ is not necessarily surjective, take e.g. $$A = \{1,2,3,4\}, \quad B = \{1,2,3\}, \quad C = \{1,2\},$$ and define $g \colon A \to B$ via $$g(1) = 1, \quad g(2)=2, \quad g(3) = 2, \quad g(4) = 2,$$ and $f\colon B \to C$ via $$f(1) = 1, \quad f(2) = 2, \quad f(3) = 2.$$ Now $f$ is surjective, $f(g(1)) = f(1) = 1$ and $f(g(n)) = f(2) = 2$ for $n \neq 1$, so $f\circ g$ is surjective, but $g$ is not surjective.

You can work out D) with a similar example.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed my question , I am sorry I need more information about my question.  That wasn't my only question.

Comment: A function is specified by domain, codomain and law. If the domain equals its image, then the function is surjective. So take $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $g \colon \mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x) = x^2 = g(x)$. Then $g$ is surjective, but $f$ is not.

Comment: thank you. I think we can find counterexample for one-to-one function also, right?

Comment: You should try yourself.

Comment: I think that, $f$ is one to one only in range of $g(x)$, am I correct?

Comment: Take $A = C = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and define $g \colon A \to B$ via $g(n) = n$ for all $n \in A$, and $f \colon B \to C$ via $f(n) = n$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ and $f(5)=4$. Then $f \circ g \colon A \to C$ is bijective, but $f$ is not injective as the preimage of $4$ is given by $4$ and $5$.

Comment: Take $g(x)=e^x$ and $\begin{equation}
    f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      \ln(x)& \mathrm{if}\, x > 0 \\
      0        & \mathrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}$

Comment: D) $f$ is one-to-one also means $f$ is injective, is it correct?

Comment: No, I commented on that.

Comment: The first version of question was incorrect. I changed the term "bijective" to "one-to-one".

Comment: Is my counterexample correct? Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand your "counterexample".

Comment: The statement E is also wrong.